# Google spreadsheet data not showing properly in graphic

Tags: google-sheets, google-workspace, google-sheets-charts

I'm using `=CONCATENATE('90diaspessoas'!B16," ", TO_TEXT('90diaspessoas'!A16))` to join two cells data into one, then display the data on a graphic.
[image]
[image]

The following picture shows the result that I'm trying to achieve. I made it in Adobe Fireworks:
[image]

But this is what I'm getting (Yeah I changed the graphic type, but it's almost the same thing)

[image]

As you can see, the date is appearing below the graphic and the data inside the graphic is messed up.

Is there any way I can achieve the example shown in that screenshot before?

Answer (score 1):

My approach was wrong. Instead I just used:

On column B, row 2, changed `=CONCATENATE('90diaspessoas'!B16," ", TO_TEXT('90diaspessoas'!A16))` to `='90diaspessoas'!B16`, returning the amount of visitors. Let's say `129`
Then on Column A, Row 2, changed `Sun` to    `=CONCATENATE(CHOOSE(WEEKDAY('90diaspessoas'!A16),"Domingo","Segunda","Terça","Quarta","Quinta","Sexta","Sábado")," ",TO_TEXT('90diaspessoas'!A16 ) )`
Returning the Week + Date. For example `Saturday 2017-12-02`
You can change the text between the double quotes to whatever you want, mine is in Portuguese, but you could just use:

`=CHOOSE(WEEKDAY('nametitle'!A2),"Sun","mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat")`